# CA2221: Finalizers should be protected

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, idisposable

I was looking at this rule and it says that Finalizers should be protected and we should add protected modifier to Finalizer.

I am completely confused since I am pretty sure that I cannot modify the destructor to have a protected modifier.

If this is something that compiler handles automatically, when it isn't mentioned obviously and also the fix for the rule clearly states modify the Finalizer with protected keyword (doesn't make sense).

Am I correct in saying that I cannot modify the Finalizer with any modifier since Finalize method in Object class is automatically called by a destructor?

The same problem with **CA2220: Finalizers should call base class finalizer**
This says I should call base Finalizer from derived class but as far as I read, base Finalizers are automatically called in Finalize method of Object class and I don't even have to bother about that.
Am I right?

Comment: What rule?  What the heck is CA2221?

Comment: @Hogan http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182340.aspx - Also, `protected ~Foo()` compiles just fine.

Comment: @inspiringmyself are you actually seeing these rule violations in your own code or are you just browsing the entire Code Analysis ruleset?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Before even trying to run the ruleset, I was hightly suspicious that these things should have been automatically taken care by Compiler. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This rule shouldn't apply to any C# code you write.  The access modifier of the finalizer is controlled by the compiler and it is emitted correctly as protected.  Only programs which are themselves emitting IL can violate this rule.  This is noted in the remarks section on the MSDN page

- [CA221 MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182340%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Remarks

> This rule cannot be violated in any high-level .NET language; it can be violated if you are writing Microsoft Intermediate Language.

The same basic logic applies to CA2220.  The C# compiler will automatically insert calls to the base finalizer and there is no way to stop that.  However there are other languages, like VB.Net, which do not do this and CA2220 applies to them.

- [CA2220 MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182341%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Note: if you are attempting to verify what I said about C# finalizers in reflector, make sure to look at the IL not the disassembled code.  Reflector will hide the base finalizer call in the decompiled code view but not IL

Comment: What about the rule CA2220? Am I correct in saying compiler handles it automatically?

Comment: @inspiringmyself i just updated my answer to include that. Had to do some experiments before i was comfortable answering that part

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response!

Comment: Hasn't the idea of having a finalizer which chains to a base-class one been superseded by the `Dispose` pattern which implies that only one class in an inheritance chain should define a non-empty `Finalize` method?